# How would you prove this is injective?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm trying to prove that for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|ab|<1$, the function $f(x,y)=(x+a \sin(y),y+b \sin(x))$ 
is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism.  It was easy to prove that the derivative was bijective, but I'm having trouble proving that f is itself injective.  I've tried defining two points $(x,y)$ and $(x', y')$ such that $f(x, y)=f(x', y')$ but I'm getting stuck trying to prove that this implies $(x,y)=(x',y')$.   Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(x,y) = f(z,w)$ with $(x,y)\neq (z,w)$, then $a(\sin(y)-\sin(w)) = z - x$ and $b(\sin(x) - \sin(z)) = w - y$.

If $b = 0$, then $w = y$ from the second equation, and $z = x$ from substituting that into the first, hence the function is injective in this case. Suppose $b \neq 0$.

Multiplying these together, we obtain

$$ab(\sin(y)-\sin(w))(\sin(x)-\sin(z)) = (z-x)(w-y).$$

Now, we note that, for any two real numbers $u$ and $v$, we have $|\sin(u)-\sin(v)| \leq |u-v|$. Thus, by the above

\begin{align*}|z-x||w-y| &= |ab||\sin(y)-\sin(w)||\sin(x)-\sin(z)|
\\&\leq|ab||y-w||x-z|\\&<|z-x||w-y|\end{align*}
a contradiction.

Hence, $f$ is injective.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That makes so much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Note that sine function is Lipschitz: $|\sin(z) - \sin(w)| \leq |z-w|$.

$f(x,y) = f(x',y') \implies (x + a\sin(y) , y + b \sin(x)) = (x' + a\sin(y') , y' + b \sin(x'))$

$\implies x-x' +a[\sin(y) - \sin(y')] = 0$ and $y-y' +a[\sin(x) - \sin(x')] = 0$.

$\implies |x-x'|=|a||\sin(y) - \sin(y')| \leq |a||y-y'|$ and $|y-y'| \leq |b||x-x'|$.

That is we have $|x-x'| \leq |a||y-y'| \,$ and $\, |y-y'| \leq |b||x-x'|$. So, $x=x' \iff y=y'$.

If $x \neq x'$, multiplying both inequalities gives

$|x-x'||y-y'| \leq |ab||y-y'||x-x'| \implies 1 \leq |ab|$, contradiction.