# How to prove that $(x+a\sin y,y+b\sin x)$ is bijective?

Tags: functions

I struggle with this particular function ($a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $|ab| < 1$):
$$f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2,\;(x,y)\mapsto(x+a\sin y,y+b\sin x)$$
when it comes to proving that it is bijective. Can someone give me pointers? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That the function is $1-1$ follows from the mean value theorem applied to $f(x)=\sin x.$

Comment: You cannot determine wether a function is bijective or not without specifying a target space and domain. For example: $\mathbb{R}^{+}_{0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}, x \mapsto x^2$ is bijective. But $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x^2$ is neither injective nor surjective.

Comment: indeed, my apologies, I specified the domain and target space.

Comment: For injectivity: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3565823

Comment: Depending on what theorems you already know, you can deduce that the function is onto by knowing that $|f(x,y)-(x,y)|$ is bounded.

Comment: [Indeed](https://fr.wikiversity.org/wiki/Calcul_diff%C3%A9rentiel/Exercices/Inversion_locale,_fonctions_implicites#Exercice_7), this boundedness of $f-{\rm id}$ and the injectivity of $f$ allow you to prove that ${\rm im}(f)$ is closed. On the other hand, you can prove it is open if you know the inverse function theorem. And conclude that $f$ is onto by connectedness of $\Bbb R^2.$